# Manhattan grid directions with random walk

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that takes the number or rows and columns in a grid, simulates a random walk starting in the center of the grid, and computes the number of times each intersection has been visited by the random walk. Then prints the table line by line once the random walk moves outside the grid
So far I have this but i cant get it to work right.

```py
def manhattan(x,y):
    'int,int==>nonetype'
    import random
    res=[]
    for i in range(x):
        res.append([])
    for i in res:
        for j in range(y):
            i.append(0)
    position=(x//2+1,y//2+1)
    z=position[0]
    v=position[1]

    while z!=-1 or z!=x or v!=-1 or v!=y:
        direction=random.randrange(1,5)
        if direction==1:
            v+=1
        elif direction==2:
            z+=1
        elif direction==3:
            v-=1
        else:
            z-=1
        for i in range(len(res)):
            if i ==z:
                res[i]+=1
            for j in range(i):
                if v==j:
                    i[j]+=1
    for i in res:
        print(i)
```

It should read when done:

```
manhattan(5,11)
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: What is not working? Or is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, try the following:

```
def manhattan(x,y):
    'int,int==>nonetype'
    import random
    res=[]
    for i in range(x):
        res.append([])
    for i in res:
        for j in range(y):
            i.append(0)
    position=(x//2+1,y//2+1)
    z=position[0]
    v=position[1]

    while z!=-1 and z!=x and v!=-1 and v!=y:
        res[z][v] += 1
        direction=random.randrange(1,5)
        if direction==1:
            v+=1
        elif direction==2:
            z+=1
        elif direction==3:
            v-=1
        else:
            z-=1
    for i in res:
        print(i)
```

Nothing is different until the `while` loop, and there are only a couple of changes.  First you need to use `and` instead of `or` in the loop condition check since you want to exit if any of those conditions are met.

The other change was to remove the `for` loop from the bottom of the `while` loop and replace it by `res[z][v] += 1`, this works because `z` and `v` represent the intersection and you already initialized `res` to be a two-dimensional list of all the intersections so looping is unnecessary.  I also moved this up to the top of the loop because otherwise you might try to modify `res` after moving past the boundary.

Comment: something here is wrong. It doesnt start with a 1 on the first position and it doesnt track for the first place we move so say it gets directions 2 then 3 then 2 it should move right 1 then down 1 then right 1 again and continue. Here it stops and gives [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Never mind I got it to work. Position needed to be x//2,y//2 no plus 1 for either

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit less verbose version that uses `random.choice` instead of your chained `elif` statements. I found it helpful when learning python to see the same problem in different ways, so here is a pure python and a `numpy` + python implementation.

## Pure Python

```
import random

def manhattan(n,m):
    grid = [[0,]*m for _ in xrange(n)]
    directions = [[-1,0],[1,0],[0,-1],[0,1]]
    pt = [n//2, m//2]

    while pt[0]>=0 and pt[0]<n and pt[1]>=0 and pt[1]<m:
        grid[pt[0]][pt[1]] += 1
        d  = random.choice(directions)
        pt[0] += d[0]
        pt[1] += d[1]
    return grid

for row in manhattan(5,11):
    print row
```

This gives, for example,

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

## Python + numpy

```
import numpy as np
import random

def manhattan(n,m):
    grid = np.zeros((n,m),dtype=int)
    directions = [[-1,0],[1,0],[0,-1],[0,1]]
    pt   = np.array([n//2, m//2])

    while (pt>=0).all() and (pt<grid.shape).all():
        grid[pt[0],pt[1]]  += 1      
        pt += random.choice(directions)
    return grid

print manhattan(5,11)
```